# what is the difference between -L and -n in xargs

Tags: xargs

Per xargs --help:

> -L, --max-lines=MAX-LINES    use at most MAX-LINES non-blank input
>   lines per command line
>
> -n, --max-args=MAX-ARGS      use at most MAX-ARGS arguments per
>   command line

It is very confusing. Is there any difference between -L and -n?

```
ls *.h | xargs -L 1 echo 
ls *.h | xargs -n 1 echo
```

Comment: do `touch 'the quick brown fox.h'` and try again.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I see, Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`-n` splits on any whitespace, `-L` splits on newlines.
Examples:

```
$ echo {1..10}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$ echo {1..10} | xargs -n 1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$ echo {1..10} | xargs -L 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$ seq 10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$ seq 10 | xargs -n 1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$ seq 10 | xargs -L 1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: `-L` is also a tiny bit less portable: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448379/32558

Comment: What happens when `-L` and `-n` are used simultaneously?

Comment: It's in the manpage: `The -L and -n options are mutually-exclusive; the last one given will be used.`

Answer (score 1):

Note the critical caveat that `-L` (but not `-n`) ignores `\n` if it is preceded by a blank space.

```
$ printf '%s\n' {1..2} | xargs -L1
1
2
$ printf '%s \n' {1..2} | xargs -L1
1 2
$ printf '%s\n' {1..2} | xargs -n1
1
2
$ printf '%s \n' {1..2} | xargs -n1
1
2
```

This is documented for example in the [POSIX specs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html):

```
-L number 
     [...] A line is considered to end with the first <newline> 
     unless the last character of the line is an unescaped <blank>; 
     a trailing unescaped <blank> signals continuation to the next 
     non-empty line
```

This behaviour can be disabled by using the `-0` flag, which is usually the only sane way to use `xargs` anyway.

```
$ printf '%s \0' {1..2} | xargs -0 -L1
1
2
```