# What is the difference between xargs with a single command and with a complex command?

Tags: xargs

I am contemplating about some nuances of xargs.

Reading the question:
(
[what is the difference between -L and -n in xargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623959/what-is-the-difference-between-l-and-n-in-xargs/78050478#78050478)
)
I feel irritated.

When I use a multiple argument command `sh -c "..."` xargs does wrong (I think):

Either a bug in MacOS and FreeBSD and Linux or something I am missing here:

```
$ ls *.h | xargs -L 1 sh -c 'echo "$# -- $*"'
3 -- quick brown fox.h
```

I would have expected the same as

```
$ ls *.h | xargs -L 1                            
the quick brown fox.h
```

But it seems, the "sh -c '...'" eats one argument (`the')

Anyone knows why and how to fix ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an excerpt of `man sh` (under Debian 11):

```
dash -c   (...) command_string [command_name [argument ...]]

-c        Read commands from the command_string operand instead of
          from the standard input.  Special parameter 0 will be set
          from the command_name operand and the positional parameters
          ($1, $2, etc.)  set from the remaining argument operands.
```

That means that if you execute `sh -c 'echo "blah"' the quick brown fox`, the first word after the command string (i.e. `the`) will be used to set `$0` (command name), and the remaining words will be assigned to `$1`, `$2` and `$3`.

Illustration:

```
sh -c 'echo ">>> command name is \"$0\", I have $# arguments: $*"' the quick brown fox

>>> command name is "the", I have 3 arguments: quick brown fox
```

So, either put a trailing *command_name* argument in your `xargs` invocation:

```
echo 'the quick brown fox' | xargs -L 1 sh -c 'echo "$# -- $*"' CommandName
```

... or use another command than `sh -c`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I see, it's an issue with 'sh' :-) or more precisely it's man page. The  bourne-alternate-sh (bash), csh, zsh manuals all mention the fact (I didn't know...) that you showed.  
To my excuse, the man page for the original Bourne shell" (sh) that I learned back in the days before bash,  on FreeBSD and MacOS today do not tell about this.

thank you